# Thread counter doesn't increase after the first tick

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to simulate a task manager where I can create threads and see how much they've been running. The thread doesn't increase past 1.

This is the run method in my entity.

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        if(this.GetRuntime() == 0)
            Active = true;

        this.SetRuntime(this.GetRuntime() + 1);

        try {
            ProcessThread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the switch case in which I'm running the thread.

```
switch(command) 
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Process PID: ");
                    int pid = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Process name: ");
                    String name = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Process memory: ");
                    int memory = in.nextInt();

                    ProcessThread newProcess = new ProcessThread(pid, name, memory);

                    if(memory > freeMemory) {
                        System.out.println("There is not enough memory available\n\n");
                        break;
                    }

                    freeMemory -= newProcess.getMemory();
                    newProcess.start();

                    //processService.RunProcess(newProcess, freeMemory);

                    processList.add(newProcess);        
                    break;

                case 5:
                    for(int i = 0; i < processList.size(); i++) {
                        ProcessThread currentProcess = processList.get(i);

                        System.out.println(currentProcess.getProcessName() + "has been running for " + 
                                           currentProcess.GetRuntime() + "s - consuming " + 
                                           currentProcess.getMemory() + " MB");
                    }
                    System.out.println(freeMemory + " MB left.\n\n");
                    break;
             }
```

When the command 5 is given the result should be:
Thread-1 has been running for 5s - consuming 100MB

All my threads are returning 1s of runtime.

Comment: Your thread increments the value by 1 and that's it, it never changes it again. Why would you think that it should print anything other than 1?

Comment: Shouldn’t the thread continuously run?

Comment: No. It does exactly what its run method tells it to do, then terminates.

Answer (score -1):

Your thread is sleeping for 10 seconds not 1s.
Change `ProcessThread.sleep(10000);` to `ProcessThread.sleep(1000);`

And you need a loop in your runtime implementation as commented by other used

Answer (score -1):

Found my error, i should've added a loop inside the run function

```
while(true) {
            this.SetRuntime(this.GetRuntime() + 1);

            try {
                ProcessThread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This now increases the counter the way I intended it to.